# Create a triangle that continuously rotates around it’s y-axis in OpenGl

Tags: c++, opengl

Im wondering how to rotate a OpenGL triangle around its Y-Axis in OpenGL,
Ive been able to translate the triangle from object space to clip space.
Im wondering if anyone has any experience with this issue and may be able to lend a hand.

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace glm;

const int windowWidth = 1024; 
const int windowHeight = 768;

GLuint VBO;
const int NUMVERTS = 3;
GLuint gModelToWorldTransformLocation;
GLuint gWorldToViewTransformLocation;
GLuint gProjectionTransformLocation;
struct SimpleVertex
{
    vec3        pos;
    vec4        colour; 
};

static void renderSceneCallBack()
{
    static mat4 modelToWorldTransform = mat4(1.0f);
    static mat4 worldToViewTransform = lookAt(
        vec3(0.0f,0.0f,3.0f), // position of your camera, in world space
        vec3(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f), // look at in world space
        vec3(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f)  // Camera up direction (set to 0,-1,0 to look upside-down)
); 
    static mat4 projectionTransform = perspective(45.0f, (float)windowWidth / (float)windowHeight, 1.0f, 100.0f);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(gModelToWorldTransformLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, &modelToWorldTransform[0][0]);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(gWorldToViewTransformLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, &worldToViewTransform[0][0]);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(gProjectionTransformLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, &projectionTransform[0][0]);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(SimpleVertex), 0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(SimpleVertex), (const GLvoid*)12);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, NUMVERTS);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

static void initializeGlutCallbacks()
{
    glutDisplayFunc(renderSceneCallBack);
    glutIdleFunc(renderSceneCallBack);
}

static void createVertexBuffer()
{
    // Create some vertices to put in our VBO.
    // Create vertex buffer
    SimpleVertex vertices[] =
    {
        {vec3(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f), vec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)},
        {vec3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f),  vec4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)},
        {vec3( 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f),  vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)}
    };

    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(SimpleVertex) * 3, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

static void addShader(GLuint shaderProgram, const char* pShaderText, GLenum shaderType)
{
    GLuint shaderObj = glCreateShader(shaderType);

    if (shaderObj == 0) 
    {
        cerr<<"Error creating shader type "<<shaderType<<endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    const GLchar* p[1];
    p[0] = pShaderText;
    GLint Lengths[1];
    Lengths[0]= strlen(pShaderText);
    glShaderSource(shaderObj, 1, p, Lengths);
    glCompileShader(shaderObj);
    GLint success;
    glGetShaderiv(shaderObj, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) 
    {
        GLchar InfoLog[1024];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderObj, 1024, NULL, InfoLog);
        cerr<<"Error compiling shader type "<<shaderType<<": "<<InfoLog<<endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, shaderObj);
}

const string readFileToString(char* filename)
{
    ifstream file (filename, ios::in);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        stringstream continut;
        continut << file.rdbuf();
        continut << '\0';
        return continut.str();
    }
    return "";
}

static void buildShaders()
{
    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();

    if (shaderProgram == 0) 
    {
        cerr<<"Error creating shader program\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    string VS = readFileToString("vertexShader.glsl");
    string FS = readFileToString("fragmentShader.glsl");

    addShader(shaderProgram, VS.c_str(), GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    addShader(shaderProgram, FS.c_str(), GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    GLint success = 0;
    GLchar errorLog[1024] = { 0 };

    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if (success == 0) 
    {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, sizeof(errorLog), NULL, errorLog);
        cerr<<"Error linking shader program: "<<errorLog<<endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    glValidateProgram(shaderProgram);
    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) 
    {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, sizeof(errorLog), NULL, errorLog);
        cerr<<"Error linking shader program: "<<errorLog<<endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

    gModelToWorldTransformLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "gModelToWorldTransform");
    //assert(gModelToWorldTransformLocation != 0xFFFFFFFF);
    gWorldToViewTransformLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "gWorldToViewTransform");
    //assert(gWorldToViewTransformLocation != 0xFFFFFFFF);
    gProjectionTransformLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "gProjectionTransform"); 
    //assert(gProjectionTransformLocation != 0xFFFFFFFF);

}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("Transformations");

    initializeGlutCallbacks();

    // Must be done after glut is initialized!
    GLenum res = glewInit();
    if (res != GLEW_OK) 
    {
        cerr<<"Error: "<<glewGetErrorString(res)<<"\n";
        return 1;
    }

    buildShaders();

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); 

    // Create a vertex buffer
    createVertexBuffer();

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

VertexShader

```
#version 330

layout (location = 0) in vec3 Position;
layout (location = 1) in vec4 Colour;

out vec4 Colour0;

uniform mat4 gModelToWorldTransform;
uniform mat4 gWorldToViewTransform;
uniform mat4 gProjectionTransform;

void main()
{  
    vec4 vertexPositionInModelSpace = vec4(Position, 1);
    vec4 vertexInWorldSpace = gModelToWorldTransform * vertexPositionInModelSpace;
    vec4 vertexInViewSpace = gWorldToViewTransform * vertexInWorldSpace;
    vec4 vertexInHomogeneousClipSpace = gProjectionTransform * vertexInViewSpace;
    gl_Position = vertexInHomogeneousClipSpace;
    Colour0 = Colour;
}
```

FragmentShader

```
#version 330

in vec4 Colour0;

out vec4 FragColor;

void main()
{
    FragColor = Colour0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a float variable for rotation and create rotation matrix from it once then store it. Every frame you should have the world matrix updated like this: modelToWorldTransform = rotationTransform * modelToWorldTransform; See wikipedia for creating the rotation matrix around y: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Basic_rotations

EDIT: I suppose your having trouble with affine transformations. To move (no matter how - translate, rotate) an object in the world, you have to apply a transformation to it.
Currently, you are applying one transformation, which is translation to the position 0, 0, 3.
So far, so good. But your triangle is static(it doesn't move). So to rotate it, you need to apply another transformation (represented by a matrix, again). But if you always apply one and the same rotation, the triangle will be rotated against its original transform but it won't move once again. So you need to apply a rotation every frame, store the result in the modeltoworldtransform and then on next frame repeat the step. e.g in the renderCallback:

```
static mat4 modelToWorldTransform = mat4(1.0f);
static mat4 rotationTransform = <rotation by the described in wiki way>;

modelToWorldTransform = rotationTransform * modelToWorldTransform;
```

Also, order of multiplying matrices matters, because their multiplication (which we use to get transform from object to camera space) is not commutative and A * B is different from B * A. I highly recommend you to read more about linear algebra and it will help you understand what happens "behind the scenes". Many books about graphics for game devs explain it in a pretty good and understandable way. "Mathematics for 3D Game Programming and Computer Graphics" by Eric Lengyel kicks ass. It even helped me when I studied maths in university ;).

Comment: I'm still not sure what to do. Has this method worked for you?

Comment: I see you are having trouble there. I edited my answer so as to explain the basics.

Comment: <rotation by the described in wiki way> ive been trying to use (0.0f,1.0f,0.0f) however i keep getting error saying cannot  convert float to glm::detail::tmat4*4<glm::lowp_float>

Comment: can you paste the code that makes the rotation matrix, please?

Comment: static mat4 modelToWorldTransform = mat4(1.0f);
 static mat4 rotationTransform = (0f,1.0f,0.0f) ;
 modelToWorldTransform = rotationTransform * modelToWorldTransform;

Comment: Why are you making it like this?

Comment: I know how to do it now. I have to use glm rotate and translate. I dont need to construct matrix myself

Comment: But it will be good not only to use the functions but know what they do instead of you :)

Comment: Thanks BlackCat, i was just completely overthinking the assignment and i appreciate you explaining it to me.